# Another Missing syntax post

Tags: python

Right, So I'm writing code for the amount of fuel a train will need to reach a certain destination, these are the restrictions/necessity for the code:

Ask the user how many Kilometers the journey will be
Only continue if the user enters a value greater than zero
Set the amount of fuel to a number 100x greater that the number of Kilometers
Not allow the amount of fuel to be less than 1500 units
Display the amount of fuel needed

And this is what I got so far, It states there are syntax errors but I can't find them as I am rather new to coding in general.
I don't know why it didn't all go in the box

```
Km = 0 

Fuel = 0

Extra = 0

print ("How long is the journey in Km?")

Km = input("Number of Km")

if Km == 0:
    Fuel = Kilometers*100

    if Fuel == 0 < 1500:
        Extra == 1500-Kilometers
        Fuel == Fuel + Extra
        print ("An extra" +Extra "units of fuel were added")
    else    
else
    print ("Please enter a valid number")

print ("You need" +Fuel "units of fuel to reach your destination")
```

Comment: `==` is use to compare, `=` is use to set variables

Comment: `print ("An extra" +Extra "units`: you're lacking a `+` sign between extra and units to _sum_ the strings.

Comment: "It states there are syntax errors". "It" does not state at what line they are? Python usually does.

Comment: You can't compare Fuel to 0 and 1500 at the same time. Decide which one you mean.

Comment: @stark I think he means both so: `Fuel > 0 and Fuel < 1500`

Comment: That would be `if 0 < Fuel < 1500:`.

Comment: To the OP: If you really want to learn Python it might be a good idea to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

```
Km = 0 

Fuel = 0

Extra = 0

print ("How long is the journey in Km?")

Km = input("Number of Km")

  if Km == 0:
        Fuel = Kilometers*100

        if Fuel == 0 < 1500:        ; == to compare
            Extra = 1500-Kilometers ; = to assign varable    
            Fuel = Fuel + Extra
            print ("An extra" +Extra+ "units of fuel were added") ; + was missing
        else    
    else
        print ("Please enter a valid number")

    print ("You need" +Fuel+ "units of fuel to reach your destination") ; + was missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really good because you don't use the coding guidelines but that's not a problem for a beginner but ok here is the correct code. You can ask me if you don't understand something:

```
Km = 0 

Fuel = 0

Extra = 0

print ("How long is the journey in Km?")

Km = input("Number of Km")

if Km != 0:
    Fuel = Kilometers*100

    if Fuel < 1500 and Fuel > 0:
        Extra = 1500-Kilometers
        Fuel += Extra
        print ("An extra of " + Extra + " units of fuel were added")    
else
    print ("Please enter a valid number")

print ("You need" + Fuel + "units of fuel to reach your destination")
```

I'm not sure if I really understood your code so just ask me!

Answer (score 0):

There was more than a few syntax errors, there was also some logic errors.  I left a few comments to explain some of the errors that I've found and fixed.

```
Km = 0 
Fuel = 0
Extra = 0

print ("How long is the journey in Km?")

Km = int(input("Number of Km: "))   # Convert to integer
if Km >= 0:                         # You want to check if it is not negative
    Fuel = Km*100                   # You used a new variable called 'Kilometers' and not Km you had set above

    if Fuel > 1500:
        Extra = Fuel - 1500         # Bad math fixed?
        Fuel = Fuel + Extra
        print ("An extra " +str(Extra) +" units of fuel were added")        # Missing + and str cast on variable
    else:                           # Missing colon
        Fuel = 1500                 # Missing statement?
else:
    print ("Please enter a valid number")

print ("You need " +str(Fuel)+ " units of fuel to reach your destination")  # Missing + and str cast on variable
```